# Cross-platform crash handler

Tags: c++, cross-platform, crash, crash-dumps, postmortem-debugging

I'm looking for a cross-platform crash handler. [Google Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) looks promising, but it is sorely lacking any documentation, and requires a reasonable amount of fiddling to actually get going.

What is a better alternative?

All I need is the ability to reliably record crash dumps, stack traces, and CPU information at the time of a crash. Alternatively, what is the experience using Google Breakpad? Has it been great or horrible?

Comment: How cross platform should that be?  gdb + coredump works nicely on x86, arm, ppc,... but needs the gcc toolchain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it turns out that google-breakpad is pretty nice after all. It's not totally easy to set up, but it's OK for what I need.

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to figure out how to build it. Any help would be appreciated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925094/how-to-build-google-breakpad

Comment: The documentation isn't great, I'll admit. I've been trying to improve that, and I think it's a little better now, see: http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/wiki/GettingStartedWithBreakpad It is a really useful library though, and shipping with lots of production software, so it does the job quite well.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a article about dumping the stack in C/C++ with Windows and Unix/Linux at DDJ some years ago. It does not use a coredump, but it writes stack frames into a log file, on internal errors, or when the OS determines a Application fault.

Maybe it helps you:

See http://www.ddj.com/architect/185300443

Comment: I know that it's old but I can't see Unix/Linux version in the article. Is there some sort of follow-up somwhere?

Comment: Uh, I see it now (there are source codes with POSIX-compatible example)

Answer (score 3):

For compiled code, there are two good options - [core dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) under UNIX variants and [Dr. Watson](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265793.aspx) crash logs/dumps under Windows.  I know that this isn't a *cross-platform* solution, but when if you are only dealing with two platforms, then having two solutions isn't really that bad of a thing.

Of course, the solutions only capture a core image at the time of crash and not the state of the machine.  I don't know of anything that will capture IO and CPU load at the time of an application crash.  You might want to look into the [Mozilla Crash Reporter](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Mozilla+Crash+Reporter) which is, oddly enough, also known as **"Breakpad"**... coincidence?

Comment: no, it's not a coincidence - mozilla uses google breakpad as it's crash handler.