# How to build google breakpad

Tags: gyp, google-breakpad

I'm totally lost on how to build Google's breakpad. There is a sln file, but it depends on a library that doesn't seem to have an associated sln. It seems to use something called gyp that I haven't figured out how to get working. I tried

```
 python gyp  ..\breakpad\src\client\windows\breakpad_client.gyp
```

and that just gives the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gyp", line 18, in <module>
sys.exit(gyp.main(sys.argv[1:]))
 File "pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 445, in main
options.circular_check)
 File "pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 84, in Load
depth, generator_input_info, check, circular_check)
 File "pylib\gyp\input.py", line 2165, in Load
VerifyNoGYPFileCircularDependencies(targets)
 File "pylib\gyp\input.py", line 1429, in VerifyNoGYPFileCircularDependencies
' '.join(bad_files)
gyp.input.CircularException: Some files not reachable, cycle in .gyp file dependency     
graph detected involving some or all of:   
..\breakpad\src\client\windows\sender\crash_report_sender.gyp   
..\breakpad\src\client\windows\h
andler\exception_handler.gyp ..\breakpad\src\client\windows\breakpad_client.gyp           
..\breakpad\src\client\windows\unittests\client_tests.gyp   
..\breakpad\src\client\windows\crash_generation\crash_generation.gyp
```

Which I can't make any sense out of. I also can't seem to find any documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to look at the command-line-options to gyp. I had the same issue. The solution is to run the following:

```
gyp --no-circular-check /path/to/build/file
```