# How to build google google-breakpad for windows?

Tags: build, visual-studio-2005, google-breakpad

I am trying to build google breakpad for windows. I don't get it. I tried installed autoconf and m4 for Windows which seems to work. But running

```
m4 CXXFLAGS=-m32 CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32 ./configure
```

results in

```
func_dirname ()
{
  # Extract subdirectory from the argument.
  func_dirname_result=NONE:0: m4: ERROR: EOF in string
```

after some seconds of executing scripts.

I searched form visual studio solution files, but they have been removed since revision 581.

So i found the related post 
[How to build google breakpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925094/how-to-build-google-breakpad).

But how do i install gyp? What prerequisites does it require?
Or does anybody have a working (VC2005) sln file for all parts of google-breakpad ?
Can anybody give me a step by step description on how to build it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is really poorly explained in the documentation, but actually gyp is already present if you've done an ordinary checkout of breakpad. Open a command prompt and place yourself in the root ( google-breakpad-read-only if you're going by the instructions ). Then just do:

src\tools\gyp\gyp.bat src\client\windows\breakpad_client.gyp

This will generate visual studio sln files for you.

Comment: This actually did work after i had installed python as well. Thanks for your help! I wonder if there is ANY documentation about breakpad at all. I know there is a wiki including some "getting started", but i do not find at least a small all over documentation. Any Hint?

Comment: Yeah the documentation is really poor for this project. There's an example project which is helpful at src\client\windows\tests\crash_generation_app though. Also, one thing which might not be apparent from the documentation ( at least wasn't for me ), is that breakpad doesn't really provide a full solution. That is, it can handle cross platform generation of dumps for you, but you'll have to roll your own infrastructure for dump delivery & server. There's socorro ( http://code.google.com/p/socorro/ ), but I found it to be overkill.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Breakpad doesn't have poor documentation so much as no documentation.

Comment: The gyp tool included in breakpad trunk can only generate projects up to VS2008 it seems. If you specify a different version, it chokes with an internal exception. The generated 2008 solutions cannot be converted correctly in VS2010. The upstream gyp can generate VS2010 projects though, but you have to specify the "--no-circular-check" option.

Comment: but this only build the windows client, how about the processor , the stackwalker?

Comment: The processor/stackwalker bits are built using configure&&make. You can build that on any POSIX platform including Cygwin.

Comment: This blog will help [Integrating Google Breakpad](http://zxstudio.org/blog/2014/10/28/integrating-google-breakpad)

Answer (score 12):

The latest master of breakpad (March 15th 2016) does not include **gyp**, which is used to generate the solution files. The best thing to do would be to simply check it out and install it; **gyp** does, however, require Python 2.7 so make sure Python is accessible in the path.

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp
cd gyp
python setup.py install
```

Now your gyp installation will work; simply invoke *gyp.bat* on *src\client\windows\breakpad_client.gyp*. (gyp is checked out one directory below breakpad in my case; change it accordingly to your setup)

```
..\gyp\gyp.bat src\client\windows\breakpad_client.gyp --no-circular-check
```

The solution files should now be present.

Comment: note: it will be available under <breakpad>/src/src/client/windows

Comment: Myself also installed separately ! Thanks a ton Mate ...