# Why linker error 2019 when linking to GoogleBreakpad?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, linker, google-breakpad

After a few hours of digging for this linker error, it wasn't successful:(

Steps to reproduce:

1. [Install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022371/5446734) `gyp` and it to `PATH`
2. Open `VS2015 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt`
3. Run:

   - `git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad && cd breakpad`
   - `cd src && git clone https://github.com/google/googletest testing && cd ..`
   - `gyp -–no-circular-check src\client\windows\breakpad_client.gyp`
4. Open `src\client\windows\breakpad_client.sln`
5. Go to projects `Properties>C/C++/General` and change `Treat Warnings
   As Errors` to `No` for crash_generation_client, common, exception_handler
   for `Debug` and `Release` configuration
6. Go to projects `Properties>C/C++/General` and change `Treat wchar_t as
   Built-in Type` to `No` for crash_generation_client, common,
   exception_handler for `Debug` and `Release` configuration
7. Buil all for `Debug`
8. Build all for `Release`
9. Link the libs located in `breakpad\src\client\windows\Debug\lib` and `breakpad\src\client\windows\Release\lib` to
   your application, in my case the `Qt qmake` file like below:

```
win32:debug {
    BREAKPAD_PATH = $$PWD/../../../LIBS/breakpad
    INCLUDEPATH += $$BREAKPAD_PATH/src
    LIBS += -L$$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Debug/lib/crash_generation_client.lib
    LIBS += -L$$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Debug/lib/exception_handler.lib
    LIBS += -L$$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Debug/lib/common.lib
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Debug/lib/crash_generation_client.lib
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Debug/lib/exception_handler.lib
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Debug/lib/common.lib
} else:release {
    BREAKPAD_PATH = $$PWD/../../../LIBS/breakpad
    INCLUDEPATH += $$BREAKPAD_PATH/src
    LIBS += -L$$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Release/lib/crash_generation_client.lib
    LIBS += -L$$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Release/lib/exception_handler.lib
    LIBS += -L$$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Release/lib/common.lib
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Release/lib/crash_generation_client.lib
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Release/lib/exception_handler.lib
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$BREAKPAD_PATH/client/windows/Release/lib/common.lib
}
```

10. The linker should prompt you by the following error:

    > crash_handler.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
    >   __thiscall google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(class std::basic_string,class
    >   std::allocator > const &,bool (__cdecl*)(void *,struct
    >   _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *,struct MDRawAssertionInfo *),bool (__cdecl*)(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,void *,struct
    >   _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *,struct MDRawAssertionInfo *,bool),void *,int)" (??0ExceptionHandler@google_breakpad@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@P6A_NPAXPAU_EXCEPTION_POINTERS@@PAUMDRawAssertionInfo@@@ZP6A_NPB_W5123_N@Z1H@Z)
    >   referenced in function "public: void __thiscall
    >   breakpad::CrashHandlerPrivate::initCrashHandler(class QString const
    >   &)"
    >   (?initCrashHandler@CrashHandlerPrivate@breakpad@@QAEXABVQString@@@Z)
    >   crash_handler.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
    >   __thiscall google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler(void)" (??1ExceptionHandler@google_breakpad@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function
    >   "public: void * __thiscall google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler::`scalar
    >   deleting destructor'(unsigned int)"
    >   (??_GExceptionHandler@google_breakpad@@QAEPAXI@Z) crash_handler.obj :
    >   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall
    >   google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler::WriteMinidump(void)"
    >   (?WriteMinidump@ExceptionHandler@google_breakpad@@QAE_NXZ) referenced
    >   in function "public: bool __thiscall
    >   breakpad::CrashHandler::writeMinidump(void)"
    >   (?writeMinidump@CrashHandler@breakpad@@QAE_NXZ)

`crash_handler.h`:

```
#ifndef _CRASH_HANDLER_H
#define _CRASH_HANDLER_H

namespace breakpad {

    class CrashHandlerPrivate;

    class CrashHandler {
    public:
        static CrashHandler* instance();
        void init(const QString&  reportPath);

        void setReportCrashesToSystem(bool report);
        bool writeMinidump();

    private:
        CrashHandler();
        ~CrashHandler();

    private:
        CrashHandlerPrivate* d;
        Q_DISABLE_COPY(CrashHandler)
    };

} // namespace breakpad

#endif // !_CRASH_HANDLER_H
```

`crash_handler.cpp`

```
#include "crash_handler.h"

#if defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
#include "client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h"
#elif defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
#include "client/windows/handler/exception_handler.h"
#endif

namespace breakpad {

    class CrashHandlerPrivate {
    public:
        CrashHandlerPrivate() {
            pHandler = NULL;
        }

        ~CrashHandlerPrivate() {
            delete pHandler;
        }

        void initCrashHandler(const QString& dumpPath);

    public:
        static google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler* pHandler;
        static bool bReportCrashesToSystem;
    };

    google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler* CrashHandlerPrivate::pHandler = NULL;
    bool CrashHandlerPrivate::bReportCrashesToSystem = false;

    /************************************************************************/
    /* DumpCallback                                                         */
    /************************************************************************/
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
    bool DumpCallback(const wchar_t* _dump_dir, const wchar_t* _minidump_id, void* context, EXCEPTION_POINTERS* exinfo, MDRawAssertionInfo* assertion, bool success)
#elif defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
    bool DumpCallback(const google_breakpad::MinidumpDescriptor &md, void *context, bool success)
#endif
    {
        Q_UNUSED(context);
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
        Q_UNUSED(_dump_dir);
        Q_UNUSED(_minidump_id);
        Q_UNUSED(assertion);
        Q_UNUSED(exinfo);
#endif
        qDebug("BreakpadQt crash");

        /*
        NO STACK USE, NO HEAP USE THERE !!!
        Creating QString's, using qDebug, etc. - everything is crash-unfriendly.
        */
        return CrashHandlerPrivate::bReportCrashesToSystem ? success : true;
    }

    void CrashHandlerPrivate::initCrashHandler(const QString& dumpPath)
    {
        if (pHandler != NULL)
            return;

#if defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
        std::wstring pathAsStr = (const wchar_t*)dumpPath.utf16();
        pHandler = new google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler(
            pathAsStr,
            /*FilterCallback*/ 0,
            DumpCallback,
            /*context*/
            0,
            true
        );
#elif defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
        std::string pathAsStr = dumpPath.toStdString();
        google_breakpad::MinidumpDescriptor md(pathAsStr);
        pHandler = new google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler(
            md,
            /*FilterCallback*/ 0,
            DumpCallback,
            /*context*/ 0,
            true,
            -1
        );
#endif
    }



    CrashHandler* CrashHandler::instance() {
        static CrashHandler globalHandler;
        return &globalHandler;
    }

    CrashHandler::CrashHandler() {
        d = new CrashHandlerPrivate();
    }

    CrashHandler::~CrashHandler() {
        delete d;
    }

    void CrashHandler::setReportCrashesToSystem(bool report) {
        d->bReportCrashesToSystem = report;
    }

    bool CrashHandler::writeMinidump() {
        bool res = d->pHandler->WriteMinidump();
        if (res) {
            qDebug("BreakpadQt: writeMinidump() success.");
        } else {
            qWarning("BreakpadQt: writeMinidump() failed.");
        }
        return res;
    }

    void CrashHandler::init(const QString& reportPath) {
        d->initCrashHandler(reportPath);
    }

} // namespace breakpad
```

Really don't know what the problem is ?!

Configuration:

- OS: `Windows 10(1809)`
- Build system: `MSVC14.0(2015)`
- Qt version: `5.8(32bit)`

Comment: Removing C++ tag as question really has nothing to do with C++. It is a question for breakpad support.

Comment: @IMAN4K running into the same issue, were you able to get past it?

Comment: I'm away from the win32 platform for a quite long time, but make sure you build the breakpad properly as mentioned here https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/v2.4.13/docs/building-msvc.md#clone-source-code-and-prepare-libraries and the rest is to link to it